# UWP / C# - How can custom page sizes be printed

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

I do not see any way to print to a custom paper size. `PageMediaSize` is the only input I see accepted, and that is an Enum. For example, I have a label maker that I need to set the physical size to 0.625" width x 1.95" height, I can not find the proper method to do so.

I believe Direct2D allow for setting a specific Page Size / Page Dimensions using [size_f](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1printcontrol-addpage) for example.
And I know WinForms does using something like:

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize( "MyLabel" , 195 , 63 );
```

I have that working in WinForms, but was really hoping to use modern XAML / UWP. I see there was an [issue on the UWP Samples Repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/356), but it was a question and was never answered.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I stuck with using WinForms?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you know the [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)? You could use it to convert your winform application to UWP app directly.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT this wouldn't enable me to use XAML, just repackage the winforms program into a UWP appx package correct?

Comment: If you want to use UWP controls in desktop app, you could check the [XAML islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls).